# TFS Online VSWebHandlerException

Tags: git, azure-devops

Clone to visual Studio IDE is not working, I get Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSWebHandler.VSWebHandlerException when I click the Clone  > Visual Studio IDE option.(or any other option to open in VS)!!!

I'm logged into to both in VS2017 AND TFS Online. VS is up to date on 15.4.4. GIT is the default Source Control Plug In. any ideas very much appreciated. My expectation is that it should just work!

Comment: What's the problem did you meet when you clone in visual studio via VSTS web page? Did you clone successful after selecting Microsoft Visual Studio Web Protocol Handle Selector?

Comment: There is no option to select MS VS Web Protocol Handler (unless you mean the VS IDE). I have never managed to clone or use the web to get any code. Could it be my rights (i can download a zip of it)

Comment: When you first time click  Microsoft Visual Studio Web Protocol Handle Selector (as the image shows https://imgur.com/a/1ncQD), it should let you to select the VS version you want to clone. So what's the step did you have problem? And can you show the screen shot which show the problem?

Comment: Hi, there is no option to select, not have I, i just follow these steps..[link]https://imgur.com/a/5xk0T and get the specified args message (and a blank browser tab). 
This is the message in the link:

Input args:
/openuri
vsweb://vs/?Product=Visual_Studio&EncFormat=UTF8&tfslink=dnN0ZnM6Ly8vRnJhbWV3b3JrL1RlYW1Qcm9qZWN0L2I4MDYwNzk4LTgxNDAtNGM3OC04NDAxLWQwYjE2OWNkZWMzMT91cmw9aHR0cHM6Ly90aG9ybnRvbnJvc3NkZXYudmlzdWFsc3R1ZGlvLmNvbS8=
Exception thrown:
Exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSWebHandler.VSWebHandlerException' was thrown.

Comment: You can clean the browser cookies or use another browser, then the selector should be opened. Besides, I show other ways to clone a VSTS git repo in my answer, you can also have a try.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to clone a VSTS git repo:

#### Option 1: clone in VSTS web page

In your VSTS project Code Tab -> Clone -> Clone in Visual Studio -> you can select VS version in Microsoft Visual Studio Web Protocol Handle Selector (if you select remember my choice, the selector won’t be showed) -> clone in VS.

[image]

If you want to open Microsoft Visual Studio Web Protocol Handle Selector if you alredy select remember my choice, you can **clean browser cookies** or open your VSTS git repo in another browser and select another VS version to clone.

[image]

#### Option 2: clone in VS

VS -> Team Explrer -> Manage connections -> connect to a project -> If the email for your VSTS account not shows, then Add an account -> Else select the git repo you want to clone -> specify the path -> clone.

[image]

#### Option 3: clone in git command line

You can also clone by git command directly:

```
git clone <repo URL>
```

Comment: Yep tried that/in a diff browser, same issue i'm afraid. I've managed to clone from VS but would expect VSTS to work. thanks

Comment: Since your problem has been solve, you can mark it as answer. And it will also benefit others who have similar questions :)